# Step in proof: Sum of euler phi function over divisors (Group Theory)

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Proof: $$\sum_{d|N}\phi(d)=N$$ where the sum is over $d\in div(N)$

Let $G$ be the cyclic group $\mathbb Z/N \mathbb Z$. Then $$N = \sum_{g \in G} 1 = \sum_{d|N}\sum_{g \in G, ord(g)=d} 1=\sum_{d|N}\phi(d)$$

The step from $$\sum_{d|N}\sum_{g \in G, ord(g)=d} 1=\sum_{d|N}\phi(d)$$ is easy since the number of elements in $G$ having order $d$, where $d | N=|G|$ is $\phi(d)$, which I don't proof here.

However how does one take the step $$\sum_{g \in G} 1 = \sum_{d|N}\sum_{g \in G, ord(g)=d} 1$$ I having trouble seeing this. Please give a detailed answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every element in $G$ has some order $d$, which must divide $n$.

It follows that $\displaystyle \# G = \sum_{d|N} \#\{g\in G : \operatorname{ord}g=d\}$.

But $\displaystyle \#G = \sum_{g\in G}1$, and $\displaystyle \#\{g\in G : \operatorname{ord}g=d\} = \sum_{\substack{g\in G, \\ \operatorname{ord} g = d}} 1$.

Comment: Aha ! So we are doing a partition of the set. For $d \in \mathbb N, d | N$, each element corresponds to exactly one $d$ and we know the set corresponding to each $d$ is not empty we get the result. Thanks a lot.